# Must $a$ be less than $b$ in the interval $[a, b]$?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

If I describe an interval as $[a, b]$. Must $a$ be less than $b$?

In my calculus book I read the definition of an integral of a function which is defined and bounded on $[a, b]$. And the area of the function is exhausted by lower and upper step functions. It seems that if $a > b$ in $[a, b]$, the definition doesn't work (the lower step function is unbounded above).

Comment: One can define $[a, b] = \{x : a \le x \le b\}$, so that if $a > b$, the interval is simply empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition

$$[a,b]=\{x\in\mathbb R\;|\; a\le x\le b\}$$
so we have two particular cases:

- $[a,a]=\{a\}$, and
- $[a,b]=\emptyset$ if $a>b$.

Comment: Good points to know. :+)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the definition.  In any real or complex vector space one may define for two vectors $a$ and $b$ the interval $[a,b]$ to be the set
$$[a,b]:=\{a+t(b-a)\mid t\in[0,1]\}.$$